# Add tracking code to override success.phtml

Tags: magento2, checkout-page

I've create a custom module to collect customer data and return it back to Google at success page.

In my module success.phtml :

```
<?php
/** @var \Chic\Google\Block\Success $block */
?>
<h1><?= $block->getGrandTotal() ?></h1>

<script>
  gtag('event', 'conversion', {
      'send_to': 'AW-11109313262/QKkuCMyiuqAYEO7VqrEp',
      'value': '',
      'currency': 'SAR',
      'transaction_id': ''
  });
</script>
```

Now at success page the grand total already appear but the script is not available when I check page source through my browser !

[image]

Could you please advise what I've to do ?

Answer (score 0):

These are the few things you need to verify:

- Path will be this to override the template.

  app/design/frontend/Vendor/ThemeName/Magento_Checkout/templates/success.phtml

and you need to include the script inside these tags  this way :

```
<script type="text/javascript" async="true">


</script>
```